# PowerShell :: Internet Explorer download dialog Num Lock On

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, automation

I'm using PowerShell to **scrape** the web and I'm trying to bypass the download dialog of Internet Explorer.

[image]

Everywhere in the internet ([example 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/1m4wp1/internet_explorer_opensavesave_as_dialog_box/), [example 2](http://sqlpowershellstuff.blogspot.com/2015/11/automatically-saving-file-in-ie.html)) I find this code:

```
$wshell = new-object -com wscript.shell
$wshell.appactivate("Save As")
$wshell.sendkeys("%s")
$wshell.sendkeys("{Enter}")
```

but when I try to execute it just set the `Num Lock On`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but I fixed by using

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%s")
```

( [Send Keys in Powershell alt+n {TAB} {ENTER}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999200/send-keys-in-powershell-altn-tab-enter) )